# PHP CodeIgniter startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/local/php5/extensions/zip.so'

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-extension

I've got a PHP CodeIgniter application which runs absolutely fine in my local(MAC OS) machine. When I pushed the project to the LAMP Server the following error comes up:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/local/php5/extensions/zip.so' - libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

I even verified if the extension `zip.so` is available in the `/local/php5/extensions` directory. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate - check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122348/php-extensions-not-found

Answer (score 0):

as it is searching for libzip.so.4, try install the libzip package.
on debian systems it is

```
apt-get install libzip
```

see [zip installation](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php)

In order to use these functions you must compile PHP with zip support by using the --enable-zip configure option.

As of PHP 5.6.0 a --with-libzip=DIR configure option has been added to use a system libzip installation. libzip version 0.11 is required, with 0.11.2 or later recommended.